# What would be the electric potential and the energy produced in a cable connecting two electronic devices on the magnetic poles of the earth?

Tags: planet, general-relativity, electromagnetic-spectrum

The earth is a large magnet moving in the magnetic field of another large magnet the sun.

And if we connect the two poles of the earth by a cable there would be energy and an electric potential in this cable by electromagnetic induction no?

Since there are anomalies observed in the magnetic field of the earth and given the number of electrons and protons involved how much energy can be produced from this power cable?

Here is a picture of the principle of producing energy:

[image]

Comment: Hello, Astronomy is about the study of the stars and other bodies in the sky.  Questions about attaching wires to the poles are not about astronomy as described in the [help]. I'm voting to close this question.  As I understand your question the answer is 0, because the cable doesn't cut through and field lines as it moves and so no current is induced.  Imagine if you made this circuit with a bar magnet, battery and light.  Would you expect to get any energy? No, and moreover you have shorted your battery.

Comment: I just want to know the energy that can generate such an anomaly in the magnetic field and that it does not fit in the study of astrophysics?I just want to know the energy that can generate such an anomaly in the magnetic field and that it does not fit in the study of astrophysics?

Comment: You can't generate energy this way,  To generate a current you need to move a wire perpendicular to a magnetic field, and that requires you to do work.  So you have to put energy in.  A generator can convert motion to electrical energy, but it can't create energy.  But in any case, this is not about ht stars or other astronomical bodies.

Comment: there are anomalies already observed which suggests that we will have a record in this cable for example lightning going from the ground to the ionosphere,
And in this shema which represents an image of short circuit the bulb just does not light up because there is not enough energy there is like even which does not pass in the short circuit wire it is quantum and given the energy at play in a planet this energy would be very large and not quite zero there is a gap between the theory and the real

Comment: Also cross posted to physics https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/640530/what-would-be-the-electrical-potential-of-a-cable-connecting-two-electronic-devi

Comment: I did not find an answer, so I looked for astrophysical answers since we are talking about a planet

Comment: @jamesk I think this question has an astrophysical /extraterrestrial answer as it involves considering earth's magnetosphere and the interaction with the solar wind. The answer will be around 0V, but low - frequency disturbances with internal and external origin (I lack time to formulate that now)

Comment: The sketch shows the setup magnetic or electric sounding of the earth uses

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic as defined in the help center

Comment: I have a question in the forum chat. Are there statistics of earth magnetic field anomalies as a function of the generated electric energy and time or frequency?